# How to stop TerriaJS from automatically animating time-dependent data

Tags: terriajs

I love [TerriaJS](https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs), but one annoying feature is that with the default deployment, any time-dependent layer (like a time-dependent WMS) will start animating immediately.

Since some of our WMS layers take a few seconds to load each time step and have thousands of time steps, this is really more than annoying.

Is there a way to turn of this default behavior and allow the user to animate only when they click the play button on the time slider (at the bottom of the screen grab here):
[image: terrijs snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the line `autoPlay: false` under `parameters` in the `<TerriaMap>/wwwroot/config.json` file like this:

```
{
    /* Names of init files (in wwwroot/init), without the .json extension, to load by default */
    initializationUrls: [
        "terria"
    ],
    parameters: {
        autoPlay: false,
        googleUrlShortenerKey: null,
        googleAnalyticsKey: null,
        googleAnalyticsOptions: null,
 ...

        // You probably shouldn't change this.
        proj4ServiceBaseUrl: "proj4def/",
        // Or this
        feedbackUrl: "feedback"
    }
}
```